# Extracting Individual Values From Firebase DataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to retrieve data from Firebase database, and I get something like the following:

```
DataSnapshot { key = Food, value = {-key1=true, -key2=true, -key3=true} }
```

From this datasnopshot, how can I extract key strings of the food value (i.e. -key, -key2, and -key3) to save in an array individually like `array{-key1, -key2, -key3}`?

Comment: This looks like a typical `for loop` with arrays situation than with firebase or firebase database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a snapshot, you can address children with `child()`:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    System.out.println(snapshot.getKey()); // Food
    System.out.println(snapshot.child("-key1").getValue()); // true
}
```

You can also loop over the children:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(child.getKey()); // "-key1", "-key2", etc
        System.out.println(child.getValue()); // true, true, etc
    }
}
```

Comment: In scenario where you happen to have one more layer of children (i.e total 3 layers). **How effective will be two nested for loops to reach the end layer ?** Or do you suggest avoid getting to that situation all together ? It might not be that huge issue for a small database **but what about the case when children count is in thousands or millions.**

Comment: When you attach a listener to a location, all data under that location is downloaded to the client and available in the snapshot. So the loop is a local operation. I think that probably also answers your second question: don't download large nodes. In Firebase: only read/synchronize data that you're showing to the user.

Comment: Awesome! Thank's for the reply. It's really helpful.